# Ios FBSession can't alloc why?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I would like to make "Facebook Log-in" function in iOS. The problem is `[FBSession alloc]` is not working.

`[FBSession alloc]` has `0X0000000`.

so `[[FBSession alloc] init]` has crash. Why `[FBSession alloc]` has `0X00000`?

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[self updateView];

SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // create a fresh session object
    appDelegate.session = [**[FBSession alloc]** init];

    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
            // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels
            [self updateView];
        }];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you did not actually wrote `[**[FBSession alloc]** init]`, did you?

Comment: yes i din't [[FBSession alloc]init] like this.